# Using azure to run java app but access not working

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

I just started to work with the azure platform and I have a Question.

I upload my app to azure and run it but when I try to access it, it does not work but returns a `404 not found`.

Maybe I did something wrong?

This is the repo that I connected:

https://github.com/idanovadia/ServerAlgoSearchImplementation_v2

for example when I run it on local host :
http://localhost:8080/getMaze/prim

now I tried :
https://searchnow.azurewebsites.net/getMaze/prim

[image: here is the screen from azure]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know anything about Azure, but it looks to me that the Tomcat Server that is running on Azure does not deploy the app correctly. Since you are able to deploy it on your local machine it is more likely that Azure has no access to your repository (or the build failed). Maybe you have some logs from the build?

Comment: How did you deploy it? And what runtime you use? Linux or windows and other settings?Please provide more information.

Comment: linux
tomcat 9.0
I created new web app and connect it to my repo

Answer (score 1):

I see that you try to package your java app to a jar file, and run the jar with a web.config in web app. This is the old way to run spring boot application.

In fact, there is a common and better way. It is just to package your spring boot application to a war package. And then you can deploy it to Azure web app with tomcat container.

### 1. You need to choose to package as war when you initialize the spring boot project:

[image]

### 2. Set the packaged file name to ROOT.war

Open the pom.xml, add the following line:

[image]

Then you will get a ROOT.war file if you run `mvn clean package`

### 3. Create a web app with Tomcat

[image]

### 4. Deploy ROOT.war under \site\wwwroot\webapps folder in web app

[image]

### 5. Restart your web app.

[image]